# libprotobuf-c & libev4 not found

Tags: 15.04, libraries

I am trying to setup Openconnect Server on my Ubuntu VPS and first I have to compile it, but everytime i run `./configure` I get 2 errors:

```
configure: WARNING: ***
*** libprotobuf-c was not found.
***
checking for libev... no
configure: error: ***
*** libev4 was not found.
***
```

When I try to install `libprotobuf-c` I get the following output

```
root@MY_VPS_NAME:~# apt install libprotobuf-c
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf-c
```

and when I try to install `libev4` I get the following output:

```
root@MY_VPS_NAME:~# apt install libev4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libev4 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-15 linux-headers-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-15-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
root@MY_VPS_NAME:~#
```

VPS is Running: ubuntu-15.04-x86_64
Thanks,
~WC

Comment: 15.04 has gone end of life and so did the support from askubuntu when that happend. Please upgrade to a supported release if you want help from askubuntu Oh and your package name is wrong: search for "libprotobuf-c ubuntu" on google and you'll see what is wrong

Comment: Thanks for your answer, okay I will install 14.04 LTS. I have searched for "libprotobuf-c ubuntu" and it looks like that the package name is `protobuf-c` I tried to install this one, and still unable to locate it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protobuf package is called `libprotobuf-c1` nowdays. The `libev4` is there, if you can not install it, you have generic repository problems.
Your Ubuntu 15.04 is outdated, please upgrade to 15.10. This may be the cause of missing packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and everything looks good, I think you were right, the problem was related to the version of Ubuntu, which I was using.

Answer (score 2):

I meet same problem in Ubuntu 18.04, and I installed `libev-dev` to fix the it.

Comment: Arch: `pacman -S libev`